# How to show tableView to top when scrolled

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift3

In my project, 
In the view 'Top' side is for one UIView and below it a tableView. I want to show tableView to top when scrolled and hide the tableView.

```
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.topView.isHidden = true  }
```

Please give me solution for how to show tableView to top when tableView scrolled.
Below is the screenshot
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

in this view bottom is tableView and top is UIView.
Below is the storyboard screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot here.

Comment: @ Darshan Karekar  screenshot shared

Comment: @VikasDhasal the view that is show ing above prototype cell means back arrow image title and 3buttons  all are inside topView?

Comment: You want to hide topview when tableView is scrolled on top right?

Comment: yes. In topView the 3 buttons, 1 title and 1 imageview .

Comment: yes. I  want to hide topview when tableView is scrolled on top.

Comment: @VikasDhasal Then `tableHeaderView` will perfectly work for this situation when you scroll up it will move up with the tableView.

Comment: @Nirav D 
 
Means like that......... func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) { self.tableView.tableHeaderView = topview }

Comment: @VikasDhasal No you need to set that in `viewDidLoad` not in `scrollViewDidScroll`.

Comment: @VikasDhasal Can you show your current code?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to set that `topView` as [`tableHeaderView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614904-tableheaderview).

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = topView
```

Now when you scroll the `tableView` `topView` will goes up with it. Also no need to implement `scrollViewDidScroll` now.

Comment: You should set topview as `tableHeaderView`! it is perfect solution! @VikasDhasal

Comment: @VikasDhasal Is it working now, check that you are not setting `tableFooterView` instead of `tableHeaderView`

Comment: @Nirav D yes I am sure. i set tableHeaderView.

Comment: i did it in storyboard

Comment: @VikasDhasal After setting it in viewDidLoad is it working?

Answer (score 0):

**Select** your `tableview` in your `Controller` of `Storyboard`

1. Select your `TableView`
2. Go to `Attributes Inspector` on the *right panel of Utilities*
3. **Set** *`Style`* to `Grouped`

Comment: You want to move section header of tableView with scroll right?

Comment: yes i want to move section header of tableView with scroll.

Comment: did you try above mentioned steps?